# How can I type "Edit /etc/snort/snort.conf " in Mac terminal?

Tags: linux, mac, editing, rules, snort

Please help me with:

> Configuration:
>
> 1. Copy the default configuration file from the package into the `/etc/snort` directory:
>
>    ```
>    cp ./etc/* /etc/snort/
>    ```
> 2. Edit `/etc/snort/snort.conf` and make the following changes:
>
>    ```
>    var RULE_PATH /etc/snort/rules
>    var SO_RULE_PATH /etc/snort/so_rules
>    var PREPROC_RULE_PATH /etc/snort/preproc_rules
>    var WHITE_LIST_PATH /etc/snort/rules
>    var BLACK_LIST_PATH /etc/snort/rules
>    ```
> 3. Uncomment the `Unified2` output line and remove `nostamp` from the comma-delimited options list:
>
>    ```
>    output unified2: filename merged.log, limit 128, mpls_event_types, vlan_event_types
>    ```

How can I type `Edit /etc/snort/snort.conf` on Mac terminal and type inside it:

```
var RULE_PATH /etc/snort/rules
var SO_RULE_PATH /etc/snort/so_rules
var PREPROC_RULE_PATH /etc/snort/preproc_rules
var WHITE_LIST_PATH /etc/snort/rules
var BLACK_LIST_PATH /etc/snort/rules
```

[image: Screenshot-attached file]

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute a file editor. `nano` is commonly recommended for beginners, so type:

```
nano /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

After editing, exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and confirm saving changed file with <kbd>y</kbd>.

---

Depending on your configuration you might need to precede the command with `sudo`, so:

```
sudo nano /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

But considering `cp ./etc/* /etc/snort/` in step 1. completed successfully it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can type in the terminal

```
open -a textedit /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

This will open the file /etc/snort/snort.conf in the textedit program.